# Ruby: How do I use active support date in vanilla ruby?

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I'm writing a Ruby script that involves date comparisons.

To keep it readable, I'd like to do things like `1.day.ago`. I thought it would be as easy as adding `gem 'activesupport'` to my gemfile and requiring `require 'active_support'`. But that doesn't work.

I've gone further:

```rb
require "active_support/core_ext/date/calculations"
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"
require "active_support/core_ext/time"
```

But I'm not quite there:

```rb
1.day.ago
#NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::IsolatedExecutionState
#
#      ::ActiveSupport::IsolatedExecutionState[:time_zone] || zone_default
```

…I'm not sure what else I need to require. How do I use all of active record's date/time methods in my vanilla ruby script?

Comment: I suspect that you do need `gem 'activesupport'` (based on the error that you're getting) but that the monkeypatching isn't applied to the `Integer` class simply by including the gem. What's the error you get when you're using the full gem?

Comment: Yes, the monkey patching is not applied. Require only `active_support` I get the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `month' for 1:Integer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to include `ActiveSupport::IsolatedExecutionState` e.g.

```
# This is not needed because active_support/core_ext/integer/time already requires it
#   require "active_support/core_ext/date/calculations" 
# This is not really needed either as almost all of it will 
# be required by the requirements in active_support/core_ext/integer/time  
#   require "active_support/core_ext/time" 
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"
require "active_support/isolated_execution_state.rb"

1.day.ago
#=> 2023-02-20 19:18:49.686473704 +0000
```

Why this is not required in "active_support/core_ext/time/zones", I can't say as I feel like it should be to avoid this issue.

If you really want to include all of `activesupport` you were very close however the actual require statement is `require 'active_support/all'` The contents of this file are simply:

```
require "active_support"
require "active_support/time"
require "active_support/core_ext"
```